# Use ParametricNDSolveValue And Manipulate for ploting differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parametric-functions

Im trying to plot x[t] and y[t] but I dont know which parts of my code is wrong. Can anybody help me?

here is my code:

```
G1 = k m p - (1 + k) p s + s (-c + e - (1 + k) p r - (k A)/B)
G2 = (500 + e - h - (1 + k) p) s
G3 = k m p - (1 + k) p s + s (-c - (k A)/B)
G4 = -h s
C1 = -k m p + (1 + k) p s + s ((1 + k) p r - w)
C2 = s (p - w)
C3 = -k m p + (1 + k) p s
C4 = 0
```

```
UG1[t_] := y[t] (G1) + (1 - y[t]) (G3)
UG2[t_] := y[t] (G2) + (1 - y[t]) (G4)

UC1[t_] := x[t] (C1) + (1 - x[t]) (C2)
UC2[t_] := x[t] (C3) + (1 - x[t]) (C4)
```

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 
    x[t] (1 - x[t]) (UG1[t] - UG2[t]), 
   y'[t] == y[t] (1 - y[t]) (UC1[t] - UC2[t]), y[0] == 0.25, 
   x[0] == 0.2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, {p, r, w, e, c, s, h, B, A, m}]
```

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[#[t] & /@ sol[p, r, w, e, c, s, h, B, A, m]], {t, 0, 
   0.01}, PlotLegends -> {x, y}], {{p, 100}, 50, 500}, {{r, 5}, 0, 
  10}, {{w, 2000}, 100, 10000}, {{e, 600}, 100, 5000}, {{c, 300}, 50, 
  1000}, {{s, 1}, 1, 300}, {{h, 900}, 100, 5000}, {{B, 5}, 1, 
  30}, {{A, 10000}, 100, 100000}, {{m, 350}, 50, 1000}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing `k` value. Also you need to set the parameters correctly in Manipulate and add TracedSymbols, etc...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

```
Clear["Global`*"];
G1 = k m p - (1 + k) p s + s (-c + e - (1 + k) p r - (k A)/B);
G2 = (500 + e - h - (1 + k) p) s;
G3 = k m p - (1 + k) p s + s (-c - (k A)/B);
G4 = -h s;
C1 = -k m p + (1 + k) p s + s ((1 + k) p r - w);
C2 = s (p - w);
C3 = -k m p + (1 + k) p s;
C4 = 0;
UG1[t_] := y[t] (G1) + (1 - y[t]) (G3);
UG2[t_] := y[t] (G2) + (1 - y[t]) (G4);

UC1[t_] := x[t] (C1) + (1 - x[t]) (C2);
UC2[t_] := x[t] (C3) + (1 - x[t]) (C4);
eqs = {x'[t] == x[t] *(1 - x[t])* (UG1[t] - UG2[t]),
   y'[t] == y[t] (1 - y[t]) (UC1[t] - UC2[t])};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqs, y[0] == 0.25, x[0] == 0.2}, {x, 
   y}, {t, 0, 1}, {p, r, w, e, c, s, h, B, A, m, k}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol0},
  sol0 = sol[p0, r0, w0, e0, c0, s0, h0, B0, A0, m0, k0];
  Plot[Evaluate[#[t] & /@ sol0], {t, 0, 0.01}, PlotLegends -> {x, y}]
  ]
 ,
 {{p0, 100}, 50, 500, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r0, 5}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{w0, 2000}, 100, 10000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{e0, 600}, 100, 5000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c0, 300}, 50, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{s0, 16}, 1, 300, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{h0, 900}, 100, 5000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{B0, 5}, 1, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{A0, 10000}, 100, 100000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m0, 350}, 50, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k0, 4}, 4, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {p0, r0, w0, e0, c0, s0, h0, B0, A0, m0, k0}
 
 ]
```